# Kafka consumer - assign and seek

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I could not understand this API design!

In the below code, we subscribe to a list of topics with dynamically assigned partition. This is totally fine.

```
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("some-topic"));

    while(true){

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        StreamSupport.stream(records.spliterator(), false)
                    .forEach(r -> {
                        System.out.println(r.key() + "::" + r.value());
                    });


    }
```

Confusion is here.

```
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
    //seek for specific partition
    TopicPartition partition = new TopicPartition("some-topic", 0);
    consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition));
    consumer.seek(partition, 0);

    while(true){

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        StreamSupport.stream(records.spliterator(), false)
                .forEach(r -> {
                    System.out.println(r.key() + "::" + r.value());
                });


    }
```

**Question:**

1. We have already assigned list of partitions using the `assign` method. Why does the `seek` method also look for partition info? Somehow I feel like it is **redundant**.
2. `seek` method has the partition with topic and offset. Why does it require a `assign` first to call a `seek`?

Answer (score 1):

1 - first keep in mind that your consumer can be assigned to many different topics / partitions through kafka API.
Then, seek and assign have two different independent responsibilities, that's why you might think it's redundant, but whenever you need to go back to an offset, or for whatever reason you need to redo an offset, you'll use seek, and for this, seek() need topic and partition info, either you used static assignment ( assign) or dynamic ( subscribe).

You cannot just use seek () without specifying a topic)/ partition, it would be ambiguous in many cases.

2 - Are you sure you need to do assign before calling seek ()? I know both can be used before calling poll().., but did not know assign was mandatory before a seek().., do you have an error message ( I might check anyway tomorrow and edit this post)

Yannick

Comment: 1) It could have been `consumer.seek(offset)`. why partition as well? at least this ok 2) assign is mandatory - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition <topic>` - does not seem to make any sense!

Comment: It could no be seek(offset) only because how do you know for which topic or partition you want to change your offset position? Your consumer can be bound to multiple topics / partitions. As for why calling assign() before, I think it's because you need the Kafka cluster be aware of what topic/ partition you're bound, in order to maintain internal state of your consumer_offsets for example

Answer (score 1):

Short answer -
It is not necessary to always call "seek" after "assign".

Long answer -

```
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("some-topic")); and 
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition));
```

Do similar job except for one detail -

"subscribe" allocates the topic to the consumer which belongs to a consumer group. This takes care of any future rebalances i.e. in case new partitions are added to the topic the consumer group will atomatically adjust its consumer to consume from the new partition.

"assign" gives more power and responsibility to the caller code. It will not do any rebalancing and caller is responsible for committing the offsets.
Call "seek" only if you wish to start consuming from a specific offset. In this case it is offset "0", which is same as initial assignment so that makes it redundant.
The seek is used to go to a specific offset